# how to pass a scenario in protractor even though one of the step is failing which is optional

Tags: protractor

[image: add master obligation]

Hi, I have a scenario to add the master obligtion details. The forms will get option to select only in few combinations (say for period of apr 1986 i dont have any forms to select and it is ok) but the test is failing saying index out of bound.how to avoid this?

Comment: Can you give some more info, what are you exactly trying to do and on which line of code does it return the `index out of bound?`

Comment: thanks for looking into it, i a trying to add a new master obligation. So, i will give master obligation name, module, location, centre of obligation, type, year,periods and forms and reports may or may not available depends on the combination of above. i have by default asked to select the first dropdown in forms and if it is not available the block is failing. but  it is ok if the form is not available. how to make that condition here?

Comment: Html code @kav.
Simply check it  if element `isDisplayed` or `isPresent` then only `select` or else don't.

Comment: @KishanPatel..yes right...you are brilliant...i will update my code...thanks

Comment: Then use `isPresent` in stead of `isDisplayed`. `isPresent` checks if it is present in the DOM. `isDisplayed` checks if it is present in the DOM **AND** it is visible. 

If you check if `isDisplayed` and it is not in the DOM it wil still fail. Keep in mind that both methods are promises so you first need to resolve them before you can use the result

Comment: @wswebcreation thankyou! I will update the code and let you know

Comment: @KishanPatel,@wswebcreation, i have updated my code like this then also failing                                  element.all(by.id('s2id_txtForms')).get(0).click();
  var forms = element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.Forms.list')).get(0)
   forms.isPresent().then(function (isDisplayed) {
            if (isDisplayed) {
                forms.click();
            }
           })

Comment: I need Html code for the page. I can't say from here

Comment: html code: https://pastebin.com/ntK4R3Ev  for forms dropdown link

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.You can also use `count()` method to decide if there are any options in the list

```
var forms = element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.Forms.list'));
forms.count().then(function(totalCountOfList){
   if(totalCountOfList) {
     forms.get(0).click();
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks @sudharsan..i will give a try and let you know